# Finding the same value in a column and only returning rows without the same value

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a query that i have to find the DiscountPercent that are the same and not show the rows with the same DiscountPercent. I have tryd this and it brings back the values that are the same

```
SELECT
    ProductName,DiscountPercent
FROM
    Products 
WHERE
    DiscountPercent in (SELECT DiscountPercent
                        FROM Products
                        GROUP BY DiscountPercent
                        HAVING COUNT(*) < 1)
ORDER BY
    ProductName;
```

What i want to accomplish is to bring in the products that don't have the same discount percentage. I don't think i am doing this the right way.What is the correct way of doing this?

This is some data in the ProductName and in the DiscountPercentage

```
ProductName        DiscountPercent
Fender Precision     30.00
Fender Stractocaster 30.00
Gibson Les Paul      30.00
Gibson SG            52.00
Hofner Icon          25.00
Ludwig 5-piece       30.00
Rodriguez Cabelle    39.00
Tama 5-piece         15.00
Washburn D10         0.00
Yamaha FG700s        38.00
```

The Desired result that must use a subquery

```
ProductName       DiscountPercent
Fender Precision    30.00
Gibson SG           52.00
Hofner Icon         25.00
Rodrgiguez Cabelle  39.00
Tama 5-piece        15.00
Washiburn D10       0.00
Yamaha FG700s       38.00
```

Comment: Provide a short set of data, plus the desired output.

Comment: The answer will probably involve a LEFT JOIN, but the definition is too muddled for me to make a stab at it.

Comment: @RickJames Is that better?

Comment: Why is the row with `Fender Precision` returned? It has 30, as 3 other rows do.

Comment: And your query (`HAVING COUNT(*) < 1`) will return - guaranteed - 0 rows. Perhaps you meant ` = 1` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(ProductName), DiscountPercent
   FROM Products 
   GROUP BY DiscountPercent;
```

You might find the output from this interesting:

```
SELECT DiscountPercent,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ProductName)
   FROM Products 
   GROUP BY DiscountPercent;
```

Comment: This definitely got the job done. But is there no way to do it with a subquery?

Comment: In many cases a subquery is less efficient.  Perhaps it can be done with a subquery.